# Tasker getting wifi info for unconnected networks

Tags: tasker

Is it possible to discover signal strength info for unconnected networks? I want to switch networks if the current signal is weak AND there is a stronger signal available. I have hunted for a relevant plugin to no avail. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround you could use:

This workaround involves:

- creating a simple tasker profile which notifies you when an unconnected WLAN with a good signal is detected.
- creating a  notification (flash/blink/notification flash)-as you wish which will alert you when a good signal is available nearby.

  - connecting to a WLAN AP which has been classified as having a good signal

This involves using a %WIFII which shows information on detected WLAN APs ( useful info on mac address, signal strength, broadcast channel etc)

**Task**

A1:Alert >> Flash (or Notify LED or vibrate).
   Text: WLAN APs with good signal available
   Since WIFI signal strength ranges from 1-9 you may define strong signal as those above 5 (its up to you) See screenshot.

[image: Signal scale tasker]

<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

A2: Net >> WiFi >> Set-On [If %WIFI~Off]

**Profile**

You can accomplish this by using a WifiNear profile to detect nearby WLAN APs.

In the profile tab, select State >> Wifi Near (You may put additional info for SSID/MAC/Channel if you want to connect to a specific AP) 
but if you want detection for any access point leave as it is.
Also you can leave toggle wifi unticked if "Keep Wi-Fi ON" option is enabled in advanced wifi settings

Note: When any profile has a WiFi Near state, it will do regular scans for nearby APs (roughly every 120 secs default). 
You may change this in preferences of Tasker

Limitations:

- Once connected to a WLAN AP automatically, the context scan will be ignored until you move out of range of your currently connected AP.
- Only previously saved APs are connected automatically since one can't access an encrypted WLAN except that they previously saved the password in the device.

Comment: I have tried and tested this task and its working, however any suggestions or improvements are welcome